# What's the state of Ruby 1.9 for production right now? Is it usable with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

What's the current state of Ruby 1.9 for Rails 3 on production? Is it usable?
(the last thread I found on this was of Jun 16 '09, so and update would be nice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may run into an issue with a Gem or plugin here or there, Rails 3 itself is fully compatible with 1.9.2. Myself (and many, many others) have been using it in production for a while now.

The [Rails 3 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) state 1.9.2 compatibility right in the first section.

Also, there is http://isitruby19.com/ to check for compatibility of specific gems.